# .Net Core Identity not logging in

Tags: .net-core, identity

After extracting my database layers into different projects, each time I run my app, enter my credentials and press login, it will redirect me to `Index.cshtml` but I still get the "Login" and "Register" actions rendered at the top bar. After scaffolding and debugging `Login.cshtml`, I can see that the login is successful:

[image]

However, after redirecting to LoginPartial.cshtml, I can see that I am, in fact, not logged in:

[image]

Here is my project structure:

[image]

I am registering identity like so:

[image]

So I am guessing that the identity context that I see in Login.cshtml is somehow different from the one in LoginPartial.cshtml, but I am not sure. Has anybody any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know now what was going on. I have not yet committed the changes where I extracted everything into it's own project and I compared the current solution with the one I had before the changes. I noticed that before I did the changes, the WebSite project was configured to use SSL. Somehow, that got disabled and the login failed for this reason. I don't know why there were no error messages, but in my case, I needed to check the "Use SSL" setting in the project settings of my WebSite project.

Now I am logged in and everything works as expected.